# Wish you never + gerund or verb?

Tags: complementation, infinitive-clauses, gerund-clauses

Which is true and please explain why?

- Happy birthday. Wish you never grow up !
- Happy birthday. Wish you never growing up !

In fact I'm confused. I don't know which one is true?
Up to now I have thought about the question as follows:

- The original form should be: `I wish that you never grow up` so I think the first one is the answer
- On the other hand we can say `wish` is a transitive verb so needs an object. The object should be a noun clause. So the verb will be converted to a gerund and option 2 is the right answer.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this?

Comment: @VictorBazarov I think the original form should be: `I wish that you never grow up` so I think the first one is the answer but seems that I'm wrong

Comment: @VictorBazarov On the other hand we can say wish is a transitive verb so needs an object. The object should be a noun clause. So the verb will be converted to a gerund and option 2 is the right answer. In fact I'm confused

Comment: Those are actually good thoughts. Why don't you edit them into the text of your question?

Answer (score 2):

There are semantic and syntactic differences between the things we *wish* and the things we *hope*.

When we address wishes to another person we usually employ *wish* as a "ditransitive" verb: that is, the syntax requires that the person addressed (*you*) act as the Indirect Object, the Beneficiary, and the thing wished for that person be expressed as the Direct Object. This Direct Object is a noun phrase, not a clause:

> I wish you (a) happy birthday!
>   I wish you many happy returns!
>   I wish you much joy!

When the complement of *wish* is a clause, there no Indirect Object, and *wish*  expresses something which you desire for your own benefit.

- If the clause employs a finite verb it is usually cast in the "subjunctive past" (a past form uninflected for person or number), often a past modal; in this case the sentence expresses either your longing for something you regard as impossible or only remotely possible.

  > I wish he would treat her better.
  >   I wish she were here.
  >   I wish I had a Mercedes instead of this damn 76 Dodge Dart.
- If the clause employs a marked infinitive verb (*to VERB*), the sentence expresses a polite but firm command that the subject perform the action named; there is often an implied threat of your displeasure or worse if the action is not performed.

  > I wish him to treat her better (*or I'll cut him out of my will*.)
  >   I wish her to come here (*and stop wasting her time in the country*.)
  >   I wish to have a Mercedes (*so take this damn Dart away and junk it*.)

If you want to "wish" an event for somebody you usually express it with *hope* + a 'content' clause (*that* clause):

> I hope (that) you have a happy birthday!
>   I hope (that) you never grow up!

But *hope* always implies some degree of uncertainty; your tone of voice, or further qualification, will usually indicate how much uncertainty is intended.

> I hope you have a happy birthday, and I'm sure you will!
>   I hope you have a happy birthday, but it doesn't seem very likely.

You may also *hope **for*** an eventuality, with a noun, gerund or infinitive phrase as the object of *for*.

Answer (score 1):

The expression accompanying "Happy Birthday!" has the complete form of

> *I* wish **you** {object}

like "*I wish you happiness*" or "*I wish you many happy returns of the day*".

The expression

> I wish **that** {*subclause*}

is actually a shortened version of

> I wish **to myself** that {*subclause*}

which seems rather out of place as a "birthday wish" expressed by others.

In the expression

> Wish **you never grow up**.

the four words stick together to form a subordinate clause, which then sounds like

> I wish to myself that you never grow up.

### Back to the original formula!

> [I] wish you {object}

What can we use for the **object**?  Pretty much anything, including, and often used in this particular context, the "**to-infinitive**" phrase:

> I wish you ***never to grow up***.

I believe you're looking for that particular one.  As it happens, you can substitute a gerund for "to-infinitive", thus making

> I wish you **never growing up**.

a close second.